# The smallest topology on $X$ containing $\rho_1 \cup \rho_2$ is a compact topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\rho_1$ be a cofinite topology and $\rho_2$ be any compact topology on an infinite set $X$.

> Show that the smallest topology on $X$ containing $\rho_1 \cup \rho_2$ is a compact topology.

Answer (score 1):

To check compactness we only need to consider open covers from $\rho_1 \cup \rho_2$, and find finite subcovers for covers from that family. This follows as the latter is by definition a subbase for the new topology, so we can apply the Alexander subbase lemma. E.g. see [my proof here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=1747).

If $\mathcal{U}$ is an cover of $X$ with (non-empty) elements of $\rho_1 \cup \rho_2$. If $\mathcal{U}$ contains a set from the cofinite topology $\rho_1$, we only need at most finitely many more sets to cover all of $X$, so we are done then. Otherwise, we have a cover *only* from $\rho_2$ and then we can just apply compactness of the latter topology to get a finite subcover. So we are done.